# Beautifulsoup - How can I get the li text without select?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I gtab the "get this li" text in this HTML code in python with beautifulsoup without find.select, because this row will change on other pages.

```
<ul id="product-attribute-table">
<li>
Brand:N/A </li>
<li>
Pack Available:N/A </li>
<li>
Get this li </li>
<li>
Colour:N/A </li>
<li>
Display Type:N/A </li>
<li>
Retail Price:N/A </li>
</ul>
```

My try:

```
ul = soup.find('ul', {'id': 'product-attribute-table'} #this grab the ul with this id
```

how can I search this li, which contains "Get this li" text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
li = [i for i in soup.find_all('li') if i.text.strip() == 'Get this li']
```

OR

```
li = [i for i in soup.find_all('li') if 'Get this li' in i.text]
```

the `li` will be a list with the li item that has the text `'Get this li'`.